# In Flutter, how to balance the children of the Wrap widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In Flutter, a Wrap widget attempts to place the child adjacent to the previous child in the main axis, and if there is not enough space to fit the child, it creates a new run adjacent to the existing children in the cross axis.

So, for example, if 3 children fit in a horizontal run, and we have 4 children, it will have 2 runs: The first with 3 children, and the second with 1 child.

Instead, after defining that number of runs, I would like it to "balance" the placement of these children, so that it occupies the same amount of runs, but the **least amount of width**.

In the above example, that would mean having 2 children in the first run, and 2 children in the second. But, of course, this should work to any number of children of any width.

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try to wrap it into an `IntrinsicWidth` ?

Comment: I think the only way is a custom layout. Are you sure that there is no way to predict the width of the children?

Comment: @boformer If the width of each children was fixed and known, I guess I could just use a LayoutBuilder and then calculate.

Comment: @RémiRousselet I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: Forget it, doesn't work. I don't think you'll be able to get such layout with the existing widgets. Your only solution is to create a custom `RenderObject`. Basically, recreate `Wrap` yourself with some custom rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by Rémi, I've recreated the `Wrap` widget with custom rules: The `WrapSuper` widget in https://pub.dev/packages/assorted_layout_widgets solves this.

It doesn't exactly guarantees the least amount of width, but instead the minimum raggedness, which is more precisely what I wanted.